# Jmeter web application login

Tags: jmeter

When I start my proxy server, set my browser settings to local host with specified port, and enter the URL, the first event is recorded. Then i do Login & navigate to home page. But in Jmeter in tree listener it shows message Object moved here which redirects to Login page again.
Please help how to do through recording?

Comment: can you share the screenshots that you tried? what is expected? and what is the actual behaviour? without which it is difficult to help you

Comment: Actual result- Recording process is , Login & enter my home page. But Login process is not successful. Is there any application standards which are needed for Jmeter.